# Why prometheus expression can not find data

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I use prometheus to monitor kuernetes cluster. When i use `sum(container_fs_reads_total)`, the result is 0 . How can I find pod's *filesystem reads per seconds*

[image: this is the express]

[image: this is the express]

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus graphing dashboard may or may not be getting the values for that metric.

Since this is part of [cadvisor](https://github.com/google/cadvisor) and [this](https://github.com/google/cadvisor/blob/master/metrics/prometheus.go#L317-L330)

Verify the k8s pods associated with cadvisor are up and running. 
Check to see that your cadvisor web site has data under /containers for the metric.

Verify in the config map for Prometheus that you are scraping/containers  inside the `scrape_config`.

Once you have the Prometheus Dashboard up, go to the Graph tab and see if the metric has any values for the last couple of days or so. 
Then check the targets tab and make sure the `cadvisor` host is a target and is up.

Those are some suggestions to narrow down your search for verifying the data is being collected and scraped.